# Upload multiple files using php to different folders

Tags: php, file, upload

I want to make a php upload script that takes two files through form

Form

image of form - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1Ivc.png

and then upload these two files in different folders like upload file1 to folder1 and file2 to folder2.

Can any body help ?

Comment: do you tried anything?

Comment: This site is not for help but to answer questions. Do you have any?

Comment: Just use two different forms?

Answer (score 0):

Create a form with two file fields. Get the fields in PHP and then save the files.

Take a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried that but it uploads the files to the same folder. I want to upload them to different folders.

Answer (score 0):

Your lack of effort disturbs me.

Check out [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) you'll then be able to move your file wherever you like (providing you have the correct permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form action="multiple_upload_ac.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">

    <input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" />
     <input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" />
```

Php Code

```
$path1= "upload/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][0];
$path2= "sample/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][1];


//copy file to where you want to store file
copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][0], $path1);
copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][1], $path2);
```